Using SMOTE Train Model and Optimal Cutoff on Unbalanced Test Data in R
My original dataset has a binary dependent variable with 3% of the values being one.  First, I split the original dataset into train and test (80-20 split).  Since it has both numeric and binary independent variables, I am using SMOTENC on train to create a balanced train dataset.  I generate a logistic regression model on the balanced train dataset, and use F-Measure as the metric to determine optimal cutoff.  But now, what cutoff do I use on the test dataset?  Since it is unbalanced, using the optimal cutoff found from the balanced train dataset is disastrous.
